# How to save and retrieve multiple selected dates using radcalendar

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I want to save the multiple selected dates using RadCalendar to sql database table column and after save, highlight the following dates in radcalender on page load, and disable rest dates in radcalendar :

i have searched about radcalendar but nothing works in.

what i have done yet ?

I have stored the selected multiple dates on radcalendar to textbox using stringbuilder as :

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim stringbuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        For Each selecteddate As RadDate In RadCalendar1.SelectedDates
            stringbuilder.Append(selecteddate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ", ")
        Next
        stringbuilder.Length -= 2
        TextBox1.Text = stringbuilder.ToString
    End Sub
```

***By above code date stored in textbox when i select multiple dates in radcalendar and click button as : 07-sep-2015, 10-sep-2015, 22-sep-2015 etc.. dynamically***

But problem is that how to highlight those selected dates in Radcalendar when the page loads,

Someone suggest me the code, but i don't knwo how to implement that

```
   Dim d = New RadDate()
    d.Date = New DateTime(textbox1.text)
    RadCalendar1.SelectedDates.Add(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in C#. Below that is VB.NET which I converted using an online code converter... take what you need from the example below to get it to work in your scenario.

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HighlightDates();
}

private void HighlightDates()
{
    TextBox1.Text = "07-sep-2015, 10-sep-2015, 22-sep-2015"; // you probably won't need to do this if you're populating the textbox already
    var dates = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
    foreach (var d in dates)
        RadCalendar1.SelectedDates.Add(new RadDate(Convert.ToDateTime(d)));
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    HighlightDates()
End Sub

Private Sub HighlightDates()
    TextBox1.Text = "07-sep-2015, 10-sep-2015, 22-sep-2015" ' you probably won't need to do this if you're populating the textbox already
    Dim dates = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(","C)
    For Each d As String In dates
        RadCalendar1.SelectedDates.Add(New RadDate(Convert.ToDateTime(d)))
    Next
End Sub
```

To disable all other dates other than those hightlighted, add a  `OnDayRender="RadCalendar1_DayRender"` to your RadCalendar in the aspx, then use this code behind.

```
Protected Sub RadCalendar1_DayRender(sender As Object, e As DayRenderEventArgs)
    txtDates.Text = "07-sep-2015, 10-sep-2015, 22-sep-2015"
    ' you probably won't need to do this
    Dim sDates = txtDates.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(","C)
    Dim dates = New List(Of DateTime)()
    For Each d As String In sDates
        dates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(d))
    Next

    If Not dates.Contains(e.Day.[Date]) Then
        Dim calendarDay = New RadCalendarDay()
        calendarDay.[Date] = e.Day.[Date]
        calendarDay.IsSelectable = False
        RadCalendar1.SpecialDays.Add(calendarDay)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your full aspx code and VB.NET code behind so we can troubleshoot further

Comment: But the code you suggested is only disble the dates of current month, but i want all the future and past date will be disabled other than selected date and also selected dates can't be unselected